# balancing the bash calculations

Tags: linux, bash, multithreading, bioinformatics

We have a tool for cutting adaptors https://github.com/vsbuffalo/scythe/blob/master/README.md and we wanted it to be used on all the files in the raw folder and make an output of each file separately as OUT+File Name.

Something is wrong with this script I wrote, because it doesn't take each file separately, and the whole thing doesn't work properly. It's gonna generateing empty file named OUT+files

Expected operation will looks:

take file1, use scythe on it, write output as OUTfile1

take file2 etc.

```
    #!/bin/bash
FILES=/home/dave/raw/*

for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing the $f file..."
  /home/deve/scythe/scythe -a /home/dev/scythe/illumina_adapters.fa -o "OUT"+$f $f
done
```

Additionally, I noticed (testing for a single file) that the script uses only one core out of 130 available. Is there any way to improve it?

Comment: About multithreading, example: `for i in $(seq 1 10) ; do sleep 10 & done ; wait` More, fore example, here: https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/

Comment: Unless you're talking about making your scythe program use threads, I suspect you want *multiple processes*, not *threads*, as shell knows nothing about threads. Look into GNU parallel.

Answer (score 1):

There is no string concatenation operator in shell. Use juxtaposition instead; it's `"OUT$f"`, not `"OUT"+$f`.

Comment: ok will try and you have an idea with multithreading @chepner